# How do I make a checkbox in jQuery lock a existing sliding window from moving and then unlock it by unchecking the box?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, locking, unchecked

I`m very new to jQuery but am starting to get the hang of it.

My Question is:
How do I make a checkbox in jQuery lock a existing sliding window function from moving and then unlock it by unchecking the box?
     So basically enable/disable a existing function in my project called - #navigate

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have the following checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='stopNavAnim' />
```

You can determine if it is checked like so:

```
$('#stopNavAnim').is(':checked');
```

As far as controlling your particular animation goes, it really depends on how you are animating your `#navigate`.  You might be able to simply add

```
if ($('#stopNavAnim').is(':checked')) return;
```

to the places where the animation would be triggered.  If you are having problems with it, please post the code you are using to animate with.

[A horrible jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/ecogo) is available.

The other option would be to bind to the "change" event on the checkbox and call some other function to stop/start your animations:

```
$('#stopNavAnim').bind('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) stopAnim();
  else startAnim();
});
```

Comment: +1 because I thought your jsbin example was cute and cuddly :)